# find image coordinates after blending

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I implemented stitching algorithm in OpenCV. What I want to do now is to find certain point from one of the original images in the final stitched image. I can find this point in image after it is warped, but then all images blend together and I want to find coordinates of this point.

For example, I have this image with size `499x369`:

[image]

Now i warp this image and i want to find point(for example 255x185)

[image]

This warped image has size `475x372` and selected point from original image is at `232x184`

After this, I use OpenCV's MultiBand blending function and i blend 2 warped images together

[image]

Is there some way that i could find that point after blending them together?

CODE:

Here i warp the images:

```
Ptr<detail::RotationWarper> warp = warper_->create(float(scale));
warp->warp(img, K, rotationMatrix, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_REFLECT, img_warped);

//now I can find where a certain point in warped image is 
warp->warpPoint(Point, K, rotationMatrix);

//now I blend the images
blender_->prepare(corners, sizes);
blender_->feed(img_warped_s, mask_warped, corners[img_idx]);
blender_->blend(result, result_mask);
```

So result is the last image that i posted and i want to find that point in that image.

Comment: Can you update with some code for a minimal working example? With your homography, you can warp a specific point by using [`perspectiveTransform()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gad327659ac03e5fd6894b90025e6900a7).

Comment: yes i found point in warped image, but what i'd like to do after that is to find that point in final stitched blended image

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: i added my warping and blending code

Comment: I guess you could artificially put a small rectangle (say 3x3, or 5x5) of some colour that doesn't occur elsewhere in the image at the spot in the original and blend it, then look for the spot... if you wanted a really horrible method! Then blend again without the artificial rectangle.

Comment: that might work, i'll try this later today and i'll give an update

Comment: with this method there is problem if the point is in the overlapped area, it disappears after the blending